# Where to ask question about setting up modems for BBS access

Tags: discussion, scope

I have a collection of old computers, some of which have modems and I want to try to connect them to the [/r/retrobattlestations](https://reddit.com/r/retrobattlestations) BBS: http://bbs.fozztexx.com/

I think it would be way more fun to have these machines actually dial in using their modems, but I do not have a phone line in my house (does anyone? :-P )

Anyway, I wasn't sure if this site or another one would be appropriate to ask about how to set up something I can use to dial in with.  Like maybe a MagicJack?  Or maybe another PC with both an ethernet port and a modem (that can somehow forward calls over SIP or something)? Or setting up a PBX?

I hope I am making sense and I hope I find a home for my question so I can set up a way to dial into BBSes.

Should I ask this here, another site, or just bring it to reddit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those questions sound *fine* for here! The folks over at Reddit are quite knowledgeable, so you could provide a link to the question on Reddit too, and then post an answer consolidating their posts (with attribution, of course) if the Reddit hivemind solves your problem.

If you use the referral link (the share button) you'll get a badge for doing so! Plus, it's always nice to let the Redditors know what's going on in the other corners of the web.